# Open Excel file in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

**I want to open Excel and Doc file (.xlxs and .docx) in Autodesk viewer using datamanagement api .**
I want to open Excel and Doc file (.xlxs and .docx) in Autodesk viewer using datamanagement api
Can anyone give an idea on this .
Any help is appericiated.

Comment: I want to translate excel files as like pdf files are translated on autodesk viewer

Answer (score 0):

In the case of **PDF** files, you don't even have to translate them in order to show them in the **Viewer** - if you translate them, then **Leaflets** will be generated for them: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/markups-leafletloader-vs-pdfloader

I think the easiest thing would be if you generated **PDF** for your **Excel** and **Word** documents and opened them in the **Viewer** like that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response